# Best Alignment of String B in a Substring of A -- Bioinformatics

Tags: string, alignment, sequence, bioinformatics

I have two strings A and B, let's say

```
A = AATCGGATATAG
B = CGATA
```

Some of you may know two types of alignments:

- [Global Alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_alignment#Global_and_local_alignments)
- [Local Alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_alignment#Global_and_local_alignments)

But I would like to implement an alignment that takes the **best** *whole substring* of A which, if aligned with B, yields the best alignment

For example:

```
A,B -- Alignment algorithm --> AATCGGATATAG 
                                  CG-ATA
```

So far I've been using the [Smith-Waterman Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Waterman_algorithm)

Does anyone know any suggestions to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what you mean by "whole substring of A". Do you want to use all of A or only the best portion of it? Is it or is it not okay for there to be gaps in A?

Comment: There shouldn't be gaps in the substring of A I choose ( the best one )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Smith-Waterman is still the algorithm you should use.  In order to get the full sequence aligned, you should change your gap penalty to 0.  This will make S-W favor gaps over mismatches and add as many gaps as are need to include the whole sequence.

For example setting the gap penalty to 0 using the standard nucleotide 4.4 subsitution matrix will make this alignment:

```
A =  AATCGGATATAG
B =     C-GATA
```